# How to reset SharePoint 2010 List forms from InfoPath to the default forms?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer

I've converted a Custom List forms to use InfoPath forms using SharePoint Designer, now I want to revert this back and return to the normal New, Edit and Details forms.
How can I achieve this?

Edit: Here is what I did

1. In SharePoint Designer 2010 I Clicked on Lists and Libraries
2. Click on the List I modified
3. In the Ribbon I select Design Forms in InfoPath in Actions Group
4. I started to design the form like I want
5. I published the modifications to the List

Now I want to undo what I did and return to the normal New, Edit and Details forms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

List -> List Settings -> there is some InfoPath forms server settings link that leads to the page where you can remove customization.

Changing default Edit/New pages will not help - you need to modify pages for default content type of this list if you want to go this route.

Comment: thank you. Your answer solved my problem, I don't know why I couldn't see it even I searched everywhere. thnx

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this in SharePoint without needing SP Designer.

1. Navigate to the list in SharePoint.
2. On the List ribbon bar, click List Settings.
3. Under General Settings, click Form Settings link (bottom of first column).
4. Select the Use the default SharePoint Form option.

You can also opt to delete the custom form by checking Delete the InfoPath Form from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you created new forms, in sharepoint designer, set the orginal dispform.aspx, editform.aspx and upload.aspx as default.

if you changed the original files, from the navigation pane, go to "All files" --> "/lists/your list" or "your library" --> forms.
Right click the changed files (a blue icon should be present) and then click on "Reset to site definition"

Comment: I've modified the main question for more details.

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX: even with your changes, my answer remains valid. At least the second part

Comment: @steve-b unfortunately it create three new forms and when I delete them I got file not found even if I set NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx as Default it still shows the associated InfoPath forms!!

Comment: @Pr0fess0rX, do not forget to "save" your changes

Comment: @steve-b setting the forms as default doesn't requires any saving

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you go into the List Settings and click on Form Settings you should see "Infopath" or "Sharepoint" as an option.  If you do not see that the form hasn't been checked back in.  Open the form back up in Infopath, Publish the form, then go back to your sharepoint list settings and select "Form Settings" from there you should now see the sharepoint option.  Select that and you should be good.

If you are looking to hide some of the questions but still see them in Data View (alot of the reason why some of us are doing our forms in infopath) you can actually hide some of them by going to "Advanced Settings" and turning on "Allow Management of Content Types" then going into content type by selecting your list, and from there you can make all the changes by clicking on the column item.  This is a great way to hide columns you don't need everyone seeing that you may need to make updates to (lookup columns etc)